# Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) on PyCharm with XGBoost

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.6, xgboost

I am trying to fit a model using the `xgboos`t package on `PyCharm` using `Python 3.6`.

When I call the `model.fit(arr_train,arr_test)` I get the following message:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does it work correctly when executed from the terminal outside of PyCharm?

Comment: @PavelKarateev This error happens to me even outside PyCharm with the CMD terminal, so I guess this problem is not related to PyCharm. By the way, I am not using any dataset. I am not really sure what could be causing the problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by uninstalling xgboost 0.90 (via the terminal) and then installing xgboost 0.80 instead

Comment: This also worked for me. See this github issue from more info: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4860

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a Windows system? If so `0xC0000409` refers to a *stack buffer overflow*. As you can see from [here](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2009/01/28/stack-overflow-stack-exhaustion-not-the-same-as-stack-buffer-overflow/)

Quoting from the website:

> The error code STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN (0xc0000409) refers to a
>   stack buffer overflow while the error code STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW
>   (0xc00000fd) refers to stack exhaustion.

Maybe your dataset is too large to fit in memory. Try to reduce the size of your training set before doing the fit.

Comment: My train set is only [163 rows x 189 columns]. That's not very large I would say, right?

Comment: Than the problem could be pycharm, which eats a lot of memory. Try to run the script outside pycharm